# Argument name generation when auto-implementing interface methods in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a little problem in Eclipse with auto-implementing interface methods for example HibernateTemplate - and its doInHibernate(), Eclipse generates:

```
doInHibernate(Session arg0) {...}
```

How do I force Hibernate to name it like this by default:

```
doInHibernate(Session session) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in order for Eclipse to be more intelligent about the name of the auto-generated variable in the method signature, you need to have either the Javadocs or the source for the library (Hibernate in your case) attached.

The documented "name" for variables in the method signature are not included in the byte-code for the compiled .class files - only by looking at the Javadocs or the original source can a more helpful name be known.